Plotting mixed effect models
I have made a spatial mixed effect model with an exponential correlation structure, wherein 'canopy' is predicted by 'disturbed' and 'water'. The random effect is 'river_id' and is weighted by 'pixels'. This dataset should be available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18LR-Tg9Lays6pZNRA4YDsxL_9US1S01k/view?usp=sharing.
The following code lets me create this mixed model, plot it then:
library(nlme)
di<-read.csv('dodgyintercept.csv',header = T)
di <- as.data.frame(unclass(di),                     # Convert all columns to factor
                      stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
diMM <- lme(canopy ~   disturbed + scale(water) , random = ~1|river_id, data = di, method = 'ML',correlation = corExp(form = ~x + y, nugget = T),weights = ~1/pixels)
summary(diMM)

Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
  Data: di 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -832.7345 -806.1621 423.3673

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | river_id
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:  0.05102449 0.6605188

Correlation Structure: Exponential spatial correlation
 Formula: ~x + y | river_id 
 Parameter estimate(s):
       range       nugget 
3.151489e+04 1.737973e-01 
Variance function:
 Structure: fixed weights
 Formula: ~1/pixels 
Fixed effects:  canopy ~ disturbed + scale(water) 
                  Value   Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  0.22512039 0.019999735 318 11.256169   0e+00
disturbedyes 0.05008397 0.014780311 318  3.388560   8e-04
scale(water) 0.00666970 0.001969286 318  3.386864   8e-04
 Correlation: 
             (Intr) dstrbd
disturbedyes -0.295       
scale(water)  0.002 -0.011

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-4.17656132 -0.91660422 -0.44142048 -0.09513729  2.17277160 

Number of Observations: 329
Number of Groups: 9 

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(di, aes(x = scale(water), y = canopy, alpha=disturbed))+
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept= 0.22215209,slope =0.00666970, col='no' ))+geom_abline(aes(intercept= 0.22215209+0.05008397,slope =0.00666970, col='yes' ))+ 
  theme_classic()+ theme(
    text = element_text(size = 12)
  )

When you plot this model you will notice that the slope for 'disturbed:yes' is much higher than what appears to represent the majority of the associated raw data (see below). Why is this? Is this a problem with the model or the ggplot code?


This doesn't get directly at the apparent visual inconsistency on the plot, but it's not clear that your assumption of a linear association between canopy and water is adequate. Most of the scaled(water) data points are at 0 or below with a hard limit, suggesting that they are necessarily non-negative with only a few high values dominating the fit. A flexible fit with a regression spline or other generalized additive model would seem more appropriate. Also, your model doesn't allow for the association between canopy and water to depend on disturbed; it might. Add an interaction.

Thanks for the comment. This model is the only remaining model after a dredge/information-theoretic approach to a larger global model which had a 'disturbance-water' interaction included. So its ommission here is deliberate.

Consider adding some details to the question about the "dredge/information-theoretic approach" used to build this model. It sounds like it might have been automated model selection, which isn't usually a good idea and might limit the reliability of your model. At least, please say more about what the pixel values used for weighting mean, why you think that variance will be inversely related to them, and whether pixels might be associated with water or disturbed. It doesn't look like your plot takes the weighting into account.

It looks to me like scale(water) is very dispersed. Have you checked whether the assumptions fr a linear model were met ? I would say they are not.
Could you tell us what 'scale(water)' actually is ? What would 'water' be ?
